# How to create a "buffer" that stores previous value of a variable for each frame

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, buffer

I need to know the value of a variable 10 frames ago.
I thought about making an array, but offsetting values each frame seems a bit overkill.

Any idea/thought?

Comment: You are likely to get better answers if you specify some more details about your environment., e.g. what framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Unity and C#, sorry, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a data structure based on a [`System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) to store the variable of each frame.

The advantage over an `Array` is that you do not need to move each variable on each frame, just add the latest one. This makes it an `O(1)` operation, rather than `O(n)`.

```
class History<T>
{
    Queue<T> data;
    public int MaxCapacity { get; private set; }

    public History(int maxCapacity) 
    {
        MaxCapacity = maxCapacity; 
        data = new Queue<T>(maxCapacity);
    }

    public void AddEntry(T newData)
    {
        if (data.Count >= MaxCapacity)
        {
            data.Dequeue();
        }
        data.Enqueue(newData);
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        return data.Peek();
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
var h = new History<float>(10);

//on each frame
h.AddEntry(0.12345f);

//get the value 10 frames ago (or the earliest one recorded)
Console.WriteLine(h.Peek());
```

I will leave it to the reader to implement further utility methods such as `Clear()`.

Comment: Does it make sense to use MemoryStream to store the values of variables until I need them?